# Get a div to go across the whole page

Tags: css, html, width, margin

Whenever i try to make a div with width 100%, it does not go across the whole page, it leaves small margins on either side(top bottom left and right),  i would like the div to go across the whole page, such as the header bar on the top of this page.

Comment: In what  browser? What other CSS is on the page?

Comment: Without a link, jsfiddle or complete markup, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set margin and padding of `body` element to 0. Like this (in CSS):

```
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And also remember about setting `margin` of `div` element to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a body margin from the browser reset margin and padding:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a CSS Reset:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

That's a simple ones, there are thousands of more advanced ones across the web.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the body margins set to 0px?  In your stylesheet set `body { margin:0px; }`.  If you want to keep the body margins, you need to adjust the width of the div.  Something like `div#idOfDiv { margin-left:-10px; margin-right: -10px }`

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding to 0 for the body tag:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for padding as the padding is on the inside of the div and is measured as a distance from edge. Just set margin to 0px if you want a specific margin set then do it like @sho suggested and set them individually.