# How to make a div tag without margins in css?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a div to go across the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744965/get-a-div-to-go-across-the-whole-page)

I need to make a div tag that will start from the beginning of the browser, not after a margin, for example when I make this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div starts after a margin from top, left and right. But I want it to start with no margin, even when I make the margin:0px 0px; it still won't work. So, what do I do to make it with no margins and is that method useable with images too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Without the `box-sizing` you will end up with a div which is 100%+2px wide and 100%+2px tall.

Comment: The margin for `html` and `body` is optional, but I usually keep it there "just to be sure" (tm)

Comment: This one worked, thanks.

Comment: It used to be that Opera applied a padding to the body element, while everyone else applied a margin.  I always felt that Opera's implementation was correct, but they've since caved and switched to using margin.

Answer (score 4):

The browser's user-agent-styles automatically add padding to the `body` element. Remove it:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You should look into [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), which would fix all these tiny issues for you.